# Formula parse error after “setformula” in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I got stuck with formula parse error after using the setFormula in google script. Here's my function:

```html
function CreateLookupID(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetforconcat = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("REPORT");

    sheetforconcat.insertColumnBefore(1);

    var lastrow = sheetforconcat.getLastRow();
    var idrange = sheetforconcat.getRange(2,1,lastrow);
    idrange.setFormula('=CONCAT(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",""),LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(G2," ",""),3)');
};
```

It produces this: parse error[image]

I just need to stand in the formula bar and hit "Enter" for it to work: works when I hit enter[image]

Tried rewriting in R1C1 notation, but then in stopped working at all even 'manually': error[image]

I also tried replacing commas with semicolons - it didn't help.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try adding `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula in the script lacks a closing parenthesis:

```
function CreateLookupID(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetforconcat = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("REPORT");

    sheetforconcat.insertColumnBefore(1);

    var lastrow = sheetforconcat.getLastRow();
    var idrange = sheetforconcat.getRange(2,1,lastrow);
    idrange.setFormula('=CONCAT(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",""),LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(G2," ",""),3))');
};
```

Entering the formula on the cell resolves the missing `)` automatically, but the script would not.

Applying in sample sheet:

[image]

Comment: Nice catch ! Just for reference, `=` is not needed inside `setFormula`. But that's a detail.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! @Marios

Comment: Good catch indeed! All fine now, thank you!